# Slow performance using xfreerdp on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, performance, remote-desktop

To connect to my virtual machine I use xfreerdp. Unfortunately, I feel too poor performance. For example, the machine has Windows 10, so when minimizing windows, you can see one frame of animation. I also wanted to watch something, eg. YouTube, but the problem is the same, even greater (animation frames do not allow for comfortable watching). Is it possible to somehow improve the performance of the connection? (I use Ubuntu, but I know that by using Remote Desktop Connection for Windows, the connection is better)

My current configuration:

```
xfreerdp /u:xxxx /p:xxxx /bpp:8 /cert-ignore /v:xxx /gdi:hw +clipboard +fonts +async-input +async-update /f -offscreen-cache -glyph-cache
```

Comment: I have similar issues with a CentOS 7 host, with Windows 10 running in a VM under KVM.  I have used "Adjust for best performance" as suggested in my answer below, and I haven't tried watching any video, so I haven't obeserved the same performance issues as described in the question above.  However, I simply observed that rapidly dragging the scroll bar thumb up and down in the Start Menu &rarr; All apps list can result in nothing happening for around 10 seconds before what is on the screen finally catches up.

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't a solution to the root cause of the issue (the poor performance) it might help a little in dealing with it: you might want to go to System → Advanced system settings → Performance frame, Settings button, then select "Adjust for best performance".  This should stop Windows from trying to animate when you minimize a window, for example.

[How to get good video performance for remote access to virtualized computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/260119/how-to-get-good-video-performance-for-remote-access-to-virtualized-computer) suggests some methods for accelerating video such as YouTube.  Some of these may not be relevant for Linux hosts, but https://superuser.com/a/261961/277264 may be relevant to you.