# How can I securely watch videos on my VPS downloaded from untrusted websites?

Tags: linux, video, remote-desktop, vps

I have a linux VPS containing videos downloaded from untrusted websites, which may contain viruses. I want to watch these videos safely.
I'm not concerned about the VPS itself being infected, I'm wary of potential viruses spreading to my local device.
I tried RDP, but it's lagging.
Is there a secure way?

Comment: Video over any sort of RD is likely to be laggy based on many factors, but some RD protocols do better than others. RDP isn't baked in to Linux and so isn't usually the first choice. Have you tried VNC? What other research have you done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get good video performance for remote access to virtualized computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/260119/how-to-get-good-video-performance-for-remote-access-to-virtualized-computer)

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/search?q=watching+video+over+remote+desktop

Comment: Why do you think (those) videos contain viruses? Viruses are usually small and videos are big. Are you going to play those videos on a *nix device? The virus would need to exploit a vulnerability in the media player software, e.g. VLC, to actually do anything.

Comment: @Gantendo I sometimes download videos in compressed files, such as a full course or something like that and I am concerned about the potential for them to contain viruses.

Comment: @music2myea To be honest, I didn't explore remote access solutions thoroughly because I tried RDP and experienced lag. I mistakenly assumed that all remote access options would be laggy, so I started researching ways to stream videos to my host PC instead of transferring the videos themselves. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll give VNC a try.

Comment: But a video is not an executable file. So if a video would contain a virus there would also need to be an exploitable vulnerability in the media player software that leads to code execution. Just scan the files with any decent virusscanner. And play the files with VLC on a linux box if you're *that* worried.

Comment: Streaming is also an option. VLC does streaming just fine.

Comment: note that while video files can conceivably contain signal designed to cause video players to misbehave, its pretty uncommon, and the threats are generally pretty "weak". you could probably get away with just creating a non-admin user specifically for viewing them, and be done with it.

Comment: @music2myear, I agree that VLC streaming is likely going to perform better than screen-sharers like RDP/VNC, but consider that when people do embed malcode in a video file, it works by encoding the stream such that the renderer exposes a vulnerability, so the exploited vulnerability will be in the media player itself.  It seems pretty likely that a video stream that exploits a parser vulnerability when locally played, will function much the same if that same stream is streamed. as non-executables, video files do not have the capability to exploit anything except the apps consuming them.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, there are various means of accomplishing this. It does seem to me that OP is overthinking things, or making things more complex than they ought to be. RD methods are one way to isolate the host, and streaming is another. An actively updated, open source video players like VLC has a strong chance of NOT having significant vulnerabilities, especially when run with, as you suggest, a limited user account.

Comment: Why not transcode the videos (eg using ffmpeg) on the VPS - then mount/stream the transcoded video?   Running the videos through a transcoder should defang any code provided that you transcode rather then copy the stream. This whole thing is a very obscure threat - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227060/how-to-check-if-an-mp4-file-contains-malware - and would most likely be thwarted by using a less common video player.  The vast majorty of "video threats" are social engineering threats that get you to navigated to a malicious URL, rather then include malware as part of the video.